# Running tensorflow python script in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, tensorflow

Im trying to run my python script that uses tensorflow library (not sure if it's relevant) in Laravel. My problem is returning any messages back to PHP after doing basically anything with TF library.

Ihave tried following execute methods

```
$command = 'python C:/wamp64/www/hi.py';
$execMethod = exec($command);
$systemMethod = system($command);
$shellMethod = shell_exec($command);
```

My python script:

```
#!c:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe

import os
import urllib.request
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TRAINING_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"

IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"
IRIS_TEST_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv"


def main():
    # If the training and test sets aren't stored locally, download them.
    if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
        raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
        with open(IRIS_TRAINING, "wb") as f:
            f.write(raw)

    if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TEST):
        raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TEST_URL).read()
        with open(IRIS_TEST, "wb") as f:
            f.write(raw)

    # Load datasets.
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int,
                                                                       features_dtype=np.float32)
    test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST, target_dtype=np.int,
                                                                   features_dtype=np.float32)



    # Specify that all features have real-value data


    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[4])]

    # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=3,
                                            model_dir="c:/wamp64/www/Laravel/resources/pythonscripts/tmp/iris_model")  # Define the training inputs
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
        y=np.array(training_set.target),
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=True)

    # Train model.
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

    # Define the test inputs
    test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": np.array(test_set.data)},
        y=np.array(test_set.target),
        num_epochs=1,
        shuffle=False)

    # Evaluate accuracy.
    accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)["accuracy"]
    print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}\n".format(accuracy_score))
```

I get all the outputs before  `tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header()` after this all prints are empty.

I'm guessing my script gets fully executed, because it takes the same amount of time to produce output as when I run it on apache2 **which works** as expected.
I run it by `localhost/test.py`

When running from php, the code produces files and saves classifier as expected. outputing is the problem.

I will appreciate any knowledge shared!

Comment: try doing a `chdir(/path/the/script/is/in)` in PHP  first because you're refering to filenames in a relative path but paths may not match properly.

Comment: Not working, note that i dont have a problem executing the scripts, but rather outputing from it. I have also edited python script above to give you a better perspective

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that output string included `\n` which produced an empty result. I achieved my result in returning a json

```
import json
output = []
output.append(item)
print(json.dumps({i : val for (i, val) in enumerate(output)}))
```